# Code for Jira Automation Rule not executed after triggering an update event

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I have an automation rule for executing some code after making an update to an issue in Jira. The code is not getting executed even after making an update (my update was adding a new component to the issue). Here is a screenshot of my issue:
[image]

My automation rule is getting executed based on an issue updated event as you can see below
[image]

Here is the code that is supposed to be executed based on an issue update:
package SuperFeature

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.label.LabelManager

    
def log = Logger.getLogger('atlassian-jira.log')
List < String > componentList = new ArrayList < String > ()
List < ProjectComponent > finalComponentList = new ArrayList < ProjectComponent > ()
def projectNames = [ 'WF', 'BF', 'EF', 'YF', 'CLTF']

log.warn("=====MOUNA CAMELIA ISSUE:::: "+ issue +" ISSUE COMPONENTS "+issue.getComponents())
if (issue.getComponents().size() == 0) {
    issue.update {
         String text = "Issue does not have any components\n"

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text )
    }
} else if (issue.getFixVersions().size() == 0) {
    issue.update {
        String text = "Issue does not have any fix versions\n"
        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
    }
} else {
    int componentSize = issue.getComponents().size()
   
    int generatedIssuesCounter= 0
     for (ProjectComponent component: issue.getComponents()) {
                      String componentName = component.getName()
                    def shortenedComponentName = componentName.substring(componentName.indexOf("-") + 1)
                    def projectName = componentName.substring(0, componentName.indexOf("-"))
                
                        

                        if(projectNames.contains(projectName)){

                        
                        
                        def newIssueproject = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectName)

                        //log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA found--"+found+"--NEW LIST SIZE: "+newList)
                        List < ProjectComponent > newList = new ArrayList < > (newIssueproject.getComponents());
                        def found = newList.any {
                            it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)
                        }
                        if (found) {
                            componentList.add(componentName+" ===> WILL BE GENERATED")
                            finalComponentList.add(component)
                            generatedIssuesCounter++
                        } else{
                            componentList.add(componentName+" ===> CANNOT BE GENERATED")

                        }
                        }
            
     }

     


    issue.update {
        String text = "The super feature " + issue + " will be split into " + generatedIssuesCounter + " features, one for each component:\n"
        
       text = text + componentList.join("\n")    ;
         // Partition a list into list of lists size 3
       

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
    }
}
```